# Is it possible to perform feature matching around a neighbourhood in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I have a stereo image sequence captured from a moving robot camera. As the robot is moving the obvious this is that instead of doing feature matching for all set of query(current image) and train(next image) descriptor, I would like to match the point associated with query descriptor only with nearby points in the training descriptor. This would save time as the number of matching to do will be minimal.

My questions are

1. Is this approach good
2. Does OpenCV radiusMatch perform the same thing?
3. There is a parameter mask for Knn and radius matcher. Can we explore this for our use? If yes, how?
4. Can anyone suggest me reference code?

Comment: You can also use Optical Flow to check where the key-points moved to, and look at matches near that location.

Comment: what do you mean by "nearby"? stereo parallax could lead to very far correct correspondences ;) but for a standard frame rate and not too fast rotations it might work.

Comment: Sorry, misread.  I was thinking about matching previous frame with current for the same camera.  But you're right, using this information combined with the previous match 3D information, you can limit the search space.

Comment: @Micka points inside a window of say 25X 25 pixel. I will match my query points descriptor with trains points descriptor lying inside this window now with the all the  trains points  as we do in case of brute force matching .This can be done because we have a moving sequence and the keypoints in current image  would be in the close vicinity of the matching keypoint in the next frame.